# Rerunning failed Container-Managed transactions in Java EE

Tags: java, jboss, transactions, jakarta-ee, jta

I have a situation with a legacy system which uses Java EE Bean Managed Transactions. It's getting `LockAcquisitionException` thrown when it's trying to retrieve something it just created.

My initial thoughts were this:

```
@TransactionAttribute(SUPPORTS)
public Item retrieveItem(int id) {
 Item i;
 try {
   i = em.find(Item.class, id);
 } catch (PersistenceException e) {
   if (e.getCause() instanceof LockAcquisitionException) {
     i = retrieveItem(id);
   }
 }
 return i;
}
```

However - when the recursive call is made, the transaction has already died - and it doesn't seem to create a new one. I've tried different `TransactionAttributes`, but it doesn't seem to make a difference. Also tried managing the transaction myself (`em.getTransaction()`), but that's illegal in CMT.

I'm not looking for an elegant fix - as I said, this is legacy, I just need something that will triage it until the whole thing gets replaced in a couple of months!

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the only way I can find to do this is to fix the cause of the transaction - so now I'm doing a `em.flush()` at the beginning of `retrieveItem()`. Can't wait to replace this app..

Answer (score 1):

Try to annotate `retrieveItem` with `@TransactionAttribute(REQUIRES_NEW)`: it will then be executed in a new transaction.

Note that:

1. the  the first was has been invalidated (set for rollback) and will never complete
2. during the second transaction, changes done in the first transaction are not visible anyway

So I don't know if it fits your scenario. But it's the only way I know to do an operation and commit it successfully if the original transaction has been invalidated.

Comment: Thanks.. tried that but it still isn't working.. I'm not entirely sure it's picking up the annotations, as I get a 'Transaction not active' error. :(

Comment: @Robert Wilson My mistake, I overlooked the fact that you use BMT. Could you try to inject the `UserTransaction` and use it to start/stop a new one, instead of `em.getTransaction` ?